# Object Detection Few-Shot training with TensorflowLite

Tags: tensorflow2.0, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create a mobile app that uses object detection to detect a specific type of object. To do this I am starting with the [Tensorflow object detection example Android app](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/android), which uses TF2 and [ssd_mobilenet_v1](https://tfhub.dev/tensorflow/lite-model/ssd_mobilenet_v1/1/metadata/2?lite-format=tflite).

I'd like to try [Few-Shot training](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/colab_tutorials/eager_few_shot_od_training_tflite.ipynb) (Colab link) so I started by replacing the example app's SSD Mobilenet v1 download with the Colab's output file `model.tflite`, however this causes the the app to crash with following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This model does not contain associated files, and is not a Zip file.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.metadata.MetadataExtractor.assertZipFile(MetadataExtractor.java:313)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.support.metadata.MetadataExtractor.getAssociatedFile(MetadataExtractor.java:164)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:126)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:99)
```

I realize the Colab uses [ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz) - does this mean there are changes needed in the app code - or is there something more fundamentally wrong with my approach?

Update: I also tried the Lite output of the Colab [tf2_image_retraining](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_image_retraining.ipynb) and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The fix apparently was https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/compare/master...cachvico:darren/fix-od - .tflite files can now be zip files including the labels, but the example app doesn't work with the old format.

This doesn't throw error when using the Few Shots colab output. Although I'm not getting results yet - pointing the app at pictures of rubber ducks not yet work.